# Creating the orderer genesis file but not getting expected output

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Creating the orderer genesis file in channel-artifacts folder using below command:
`configtxgen –profile OrdererGenesis -channelID system-channel -outputBlock ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block`

**configtx.yaml file:**

```
  OrdererGenesis:
    <<: *ChannelDefaults
    Capabilities:
      <<: *ChannelCapabilities
    Orderer:
      <<: *OrdererDefaults
      Organizations:
        - *OrdererOrg
      Capabilities:
        <<: *OrdererCapabilities
    Consortiums:
      CertificationConsortium:
        Organizations:
          - *manufacturer
```

Getting Output:

```
2020-07-21 23:02:29.961 IST [common.tools.configtxgen] main -> INFO 001 Loading configuration
2020-07-21 23:02:30.020 IST [common.tools.configtxgen.localconfig] completeInitialization -> INFO 002 orderer type: solo
2020-07-21 23:02:30.020 IST [common.tools.configtxgen.localconfig] LoadTopLevel -> INFO 003 Loaded configuration: /home/upgrad/workspace/pharma-network/network/configtx.yaml
```

**Output should be:**

```
2020-07-21 23:02:29.961 IST [common.tools.configtxgen] main -> INFO 001 Loading configuration
2020-07-21 23:02:30.020 IST [common.tools.configtxgen.localconfig] completeInitialization -> INFO 002 orderer type: solo
2020-07-21 23:02:30.020 IST [common.tools.configtxgen.localconfig] LoadTopLevel -> INFO 003 Loaded configuration: /home/upgrad/workspace/pharma-network/network/configtx.yaml
2020-07-21 23:02:30.020 IST [common.tools.configtxgen.localconfig] completeInitialization -> INFO 004 orderer type: solo
2020-07-21 23:02:30.020 IST [common.tools.configtxgen.localconfig] LoadTopLevel -> INFO 005 Loaded configuration: /home/upgrad/workspace/pharma-network/network/configtx.yaml
**2020-07-21 23:02:30.020 IST [common.tools.configtxgen] doOutputBlock -> INFO 006 Generating genesis block
2020-07-21 23:02:30.020 IST [common.tools.configtxgen] doOutputBlock -> INFO 007 Writing genesis block**
```

Comment: Do you have the 'channel-artifacts' directory present?

Comment: Yes, the 'channel-artifacts' directory is present. I have added another anchor to peers. Those are successfully added there.  @KartikChauhan